# Can I display Windows toolbar date in ISO 8601 format?

Tags: windows, date-time

**I want the date in my Windows toolbar to display in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates). Is this possible? If so, how?**

For example, the date currently appears in the toolbar like this:

```
1:43 PM
2/3/2021
```

I *want* it to appear like this:

```
1:43 PM
2021-02-03
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this.

Go to this article:

[Time and Date](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-date-and-time-formats-windows-10)

Open Settings, Time and Language, Region, and in there you can change the Short Date Format. The format you want is included.

That will change the Taskbar  (tested here) but you need to make the taskbar double height.

Answer (score 6):

As of 22H2 (win 11) you need to do the following:

- Win-Key + "Control Panel"
- "Clock and Region"
- "Region"
- Under "Formats" click "Additional Settings" at the bottom right
- Change to "Date"
- Under "Date Formats", it presents you with a drop down menu but you can actually enter custom fields.
- Select "Short date": and enter yyyy-MM-dd and click apply. That should directly update the date in the toolbar.

Little fun fact, if you now go to the standard regional format settings in Windows 11, you should see the yyyy-MM-dd in the dropdown menu too. So you effectively manually added the ISO format.

Answer (score 5):

As of Windows 11, the OS doesn't give the possibility to choose the actual format itself anymore.

They only give you "Country" (aka Culture) options. And thus you are completely at the mercy of what world countries have chosen as their time format. Another great artificial limitation by Microsoft impairing user freedom to use their system as they wish, as always coming from them...

First, the setting is now found in `Settings >> Time & language >> Language & region >> Regional Format`.

As for ISO 8601 then, I only found **Canada** time to use that standard for the date which will be displayed as `yyyy-mm-dd`, which is what you want. However you are then forced to have time displayed the english way: `3:24 PM` instead of the more objective and standard `15:24` which would be preferred. I haven't found a way to get both of those formats together unfortunately.

That's Windows for you.

Comment: Sweden also uses ISO 8601, but with 24 hour time.  I'm using "English (Sweden)" on 22H2.

Comment: @OskarSkog Indeed ! Thank you for this !

Comment: As of 2023-12-27, I found the answer from @Highchiller to be the most accurate: https://superuser.com/a/1787943/70507

Comment: I have no additional settings on 23H2. I'm happy with Canadian date formatting, The time format can be switched to the much better 15:24

Answer (score 3):

I chose Canada, then you can expand the options under that region to change the short date format, long date format etc.

I was able to get `yyyy-mm-dd` and `HH:MM` using these sub-options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following steps:

- Right click on the clock in the taskbar.
- Select "Adjust Date/Time".
- Under Related settings, select "Date, time & regional formatting".
- Under Regional format data, select "Change data formats".

Here, you can set date and time fields as desired.

Current as of Windows version 20H2. In earlier versions, you may need to go via Control Panel > Time & Language to reach that third bullet point.